# Laravel compare aggregate to value in another table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql

I have such a situation when I want to compare count aggregate with an expected number in another table. The number either matches the count or is higher than count value. What I want to do is to have two queries one of which says `whereRaw('count=v.expected')` and another says `whereRaw('count<v.expected')` to get people who have finished (if matches) and people who are still not finished (if less than expected). Problem I face is **count** being created "on the fly" and thus not working on the WHERE clause ((PDOException(code: 42703): SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column does not exist) . What could be done to fix this issue?

What I have by now is this:

```
$query = DB::table('sv')
        ->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT ON (sv.person_id) person_id'))
        ->addSelect(['count' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('count(person_id) as cdr'))
                ->from('sv as sv2')
                ->whereRaw('sv.person_id=sv2.person_id')
                ->groupBy('person_id')
                ->limit(1);
        }])

        ->join('v', 'sv.v_id', '=','v.id')
        ->join('op', 'sv.person_id', '=','op.id')
        ->whereRaw('count=v.expected') // does not work here
        ->where('sv.o_id', $this->o_id);

         return $query->get()->count();
```

Comment: For dynamic columns try use `having()` statement.

Comment: @Daniel I tried, but could not think of how to use that in this situation. Count is in subquery, so if i used in HAVING as I understand, I may get different count since its outer query.

Comment: can you paste whole query generated by laravel?